# NoHttpResponseException is thrown

Tags: exception, httpclient

I have a situation where my application calls another one using HTTPClient. The other application executes the storedProcedure which runs for more than 1 hour.

Despite the fact that I setup Socket Timeout to infinite, however I am getting NoHttpResponseException in exactly 1 hour every time.

```
HttClient client = new HttpClient();
.....
client.getParams.setSoTimeout(0);
```

I am running this app on Oracle OC4J app server.

How can I increase a timeout time?